# Oozie workflow fails - Mkdirs failed to create file

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I am using an Oozie workflow to run a pyspark script, and I'm running into an error I can't figure out.

When running the workflow (either locally or on YARN) a MapReduce job is run before the Spark starts. After a few minutes the task fails (before the Spark action), and digging through the logs shows the following error:

`java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/oozie/oozie-oozi/0000011-160222043656138-oozie-oozi-W/bulk-load-node--spark/output/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1456129482428_0003_m_000000_2 (exists=false, cwd=file:/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1456129482428_0003/container_e68_1456129482428_0003_01_000004)`

(Apologies for the length)

There are no other evident errors. I do not directly create this folder (I assume given the name that it is used for temporary storage of MapReduce jobs). I can create this folder from the command line using `mkdir -p /home/oozie/blah...`. It doesn't appear to be a permissions issue, as setting that folder to 777 made no difference. I have also added default ACLs for oozie, yarn and mapred users for that folder, so I've pretty much ruled out permission issues. It's also worth noting that the working directory listed in the error does not exist after the job fails.

After some Googling I saw that a similar problem is common on Mac systems, but I'm running on CentOS. I am running the HDP 2.3 VM Sandbox, which is a single node 'cluster'.

My workflow.xml is as follows:

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.4' name='SparkBulkLoad'>
    <start to = 'bulk-load-node'/>
    <action name = 'bulk-load-node'>
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>client</mode>
            <name>BulkLoader</name>
            <jar>file:///test/BulkLoader.py</jar>
            <spark-opts>
                --num-executors 3 --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 512m --driver-memory 512m\
            </spark-opts>
        </spark>
        <ok to = 'end'/>
        <error to = 'fail'/>
    </action>
    <kill name = 'fail'>
        <message>
            Error occurred while bulk loading files
        </message>
    </kill>
    <end name = 'end'/>
</workflow-app>
```

and job.properties is as follows:

```
nameNode=hdfs://192.168.26.130:8020
jobTracker=http://192.168.26.130:8050
queueName=spark
oozie.use.system.libpath=true

oozie.wf.application.path=file:///test/workflow.xml
```

If necessary I can post any other parts of the stack trace. I appreciate any help.

**Update 1**

After having checked my Spark History Server, I can confirm that the actual Spark action is not starting - no new Spark apps are being submitted.